# Network wide change to question tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design

It would appear an update was made network wide on tags and it has affected some sites that are graduated with tags that were not typically a default squared tag:

Graphic Design SE, in the design you can see the tags were [rounded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlKD7.jpg) but now they are square:

> [image: current tag design at Graphic Design]

Workplace SE in the design is [rounded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2oI4.jpg) as well, but the update makes them square:

> [image: current tag design in Workplace]

Travel had a nice tag [design](//dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2296037/home-travel.png) but now it seems to have defaulted:

> [image: current tag design in Travel]

Would this be considered a bug or is this how they are going to appear from now on?

Comment: Bring back rounded sexiness!

Comment: Uhhhh they are awful ugly now.

Comment: As a note, some sites with highly specialized tags don't seem to have been affected but I'll guess that's because their border decoration is set to none (see [math.se] and [tex.se]) and then there's [gaming.se] with their odd squares that are missing corners.

Comment: Our tags are back!!

Comment: @Cai See..  Darth_Vader has made the empire a better place after all. . .

Comment: I never doubted you dark lord @Darth_Vader

Comment: Good news guys: Rounded tags are back!!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was an oversight. We're exploring some potential updates to the tag editor and the experimental styling ended up bleeding into the rest of the site by accident.

Fix is rolling out now.

Comment: That is not a fix ... that is a step back in time ... -1

Comment: So you are saying you have plans to swap our rounded tags for new ones? We like these tags. :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman AFAIK there are no plans to change site designs at the moment. I don't know what the plans for the tag editor are, but I do know it's still in relatively early stages.

Comment: @rene Eh? Not sure I follow what you're getting at.

Comment: He wants to have squares everywhere @adam

Comment: This was the first time I liked a design change ... (I'm only kidding, and it is friday ...)  ;)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xfWsJ.gif ;)

Comment: Roll back means YEAH +1! Designers are free again, so my answer hopefully helped a lot.

Comment: These are now the tags I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be by design, but we can fix that...

In a user script, change the border radius from 2 pixels to 15 pixels:

```
.post-tag { border-radius: 15px; }
```

Et voila:

> [image: rounded]

Note that the rounded tags are still present in the mobile website.

Comment: We're entering a cubistic era, go away with your old fashioned round edges ...

Comment: SE should resist to this cubistic movement. Rounded borders all the way!

Comment: Hold on ... I have to down vote the answer of Adam Lear ...

Comment: @rene Are you sure you want to go down that path? There is no way back!

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR: On sites with a custom design, do not change the shape of the tags. On sites with the temporary design, you can modify their shape at will. Just don't make them disappear.

I would prefer the following change:

For sites with the "temporary design", **keep them squared**.

For sites with their own design, **DON'T SQUARE THEM**! Designers would have alerady squared them if they wanted to, don't force them to square the tags.

Yes, I shout for freedom. Freedom means that you are *free* to do whatever you want with the design, **including the tags**. The tags are *a part of the site*, and they show something about it. Today, I **SUDDENLY** [can't stress that enough] saw SQUARE tags. "Tags are...<s>round</s>square..." was my initial thought when I saw this. And it spread to other sites as well! My next thought was "The tag design is <s>100% free</s>square".

Comment: You're kidding me, right? Are all these betas going to be playful sandboxes for these, what are these people called... Stack Overflow developers? Oh my unicorns!

Comment: @Zizouz212 I don't think changes are rolled out immediately because of "sandboxing". Did you downvote?